# All my resources get duplicated in .apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, apk

I recently wondered why my Android APK file is about twice as large as the resources folder it uses. I unpacked the apk and found out, that Eclipse had duplicated all resources!

Usually everything is stored in a "assets" subfolder of my project folder (this folder contains textures, sound files etc.). But Eclipse copied all those files directly to the root folder of the apk. So all files are duplicated and the final file size is twice of what it should be.

I already tried to remove the assets, clean the project and re-add the assets. Still the same thing happens. How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some articles that may help you.

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300916/raw-assets-duplicated-when-building-apk) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27598/android-apk-export-duplicating-libgdx-assets-folder).

Hope this will help)